# Error From DB Is - Missing IN or OUT parameter at index

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

```
  MERGE INTO TEMP_DATA od USING 
     (SELECT ? col1, ? col2 FROM DUAL) incoming 
       ON (od.TEMP_13 = incoming.col1)
     WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
       INSERT (od.TEMP_13,  od.PAGE_COUNT) 
       VALUES ( incoming.col1, incoming.col2)
```

If we pass empty value for `PAGE_COUNT` then this error is coming.can we  change above SQL statement like if you pass empty value then set default value '0'?

> SQLException For TEMP_13 : 123456789-- Error From DB Is - Missing IN
>   or OUT parameter at index:: 2

Comment: i think '?' character is invalid, use something else

Comment: that is not the issue.

Comment: `?` is a valid parameter placeholder. I guess you are running this from an application, so could you show the code in which you bind the parameters and run the SQL  ? It should be fixed there and not in the SQL.

Comment: yes,its running from java application.unfortunately we don't have source code to modify it.But we have some properties file where SQL statement is coming that we can modify it.Can we do it thru SQL trigger?

Comment: What can you modify exactly in this property file? The SQL statement, the parameters passed ? It would be helpful to detail this in your question

Comment: I can change only SQL statement and also parameters passed but not anything in java  code.

Answer (score 0):

Use the below SQL, I tried it works for me...

```
MERGE INTO TEMP_DATA od USING 
     (SELECT ? col1, nvl(null,0) col2 FROM DUAL) incoming 
       ON (od.TEMP_13 = incoming.col1)
     WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
       INSERT (od.TEMP_13,  od.PAGE_COUNT) 
       VALUES ( incoming.col1, incoming.col2)
```

Comment: tried your suggestion but ending up with SQL Exception - Invalid column index

Comment: Did you replace the "null" at line number-2 with "?" mark?

Comment: sorry;replaced it '?' but getting same initial error.Missing IN or OUT parameter at index:: 2

Comment: Can you please update your Java code as well for this part only.

Comment: decompiled the jar;its like this stmtMerge.setInt(2, Integer.parseInt(nodeValue));whats happening is when user pass empty value its throwing error because its converting into number.these values are comes from xml file with tag<TotalPageCount><![CDATA[]]></TotalPageCount>

Comment: In that case you can write a if condition and handle the null values and make them to "0" that will be better.